# Computing the stationary distribution of a Markov chain (unique eigenvector of a matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains, markov-process

What's the fastest (maybe just the fastest known) algorithm for computing the stationary distribution of a Markov chain (assuming it exists)? Equivalently, the fastest way to compute the unique eigenvector for a matrix?

Comment: How about solving a linear system?